# How can my shell script determine whether it's in a real shell or not?

Tags: bash, terminal

I have a shell script that runs in my personal terminal and in a CI environment. In the CI environment, the python calls for determining shell height/width return funny values.

I would like to do something to the effect of:

```
if (I am running in shell context)
    determine height/width of terminal
else
    don't
fi
```

How can I express this condition, in a bash script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if standard input is a tty device.

In sh/bash:

```
if [ -t 0 ]; then
```

In Python:

```
if os.isatty(sys.stdin):
```