# How can Linux program, e.g. bash or python script, know how it was started: from command line or interactive GUI?

Tags: python, linux, bash, user-interface, command-line-interface

I want to do the following:

If the bash/python script is launched from a terminal, it shall do something such as printing an error message text. If the script is launched from GUI session like double-clicking from a file browser, it shall do something else, e.g. display a GUI message box.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488180/how-can-my-shell-script-determine-whether-its-in-a-real-shell-or-not

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check to see whether `stdin` and `stdout` are connected to a terminal or not. When run from a GUI, generally `stdin` is not connected at all, and `stdout` is connected to a log file. When run from a terminal, both `stdin` and `stdout` will be connected to a terminal.

In Python:

```
import os
import sys

if os.isatty(sys.stdout.fileno()):
    # print error message text
else:
    # display GUI message
```

You should check that this will work for you, though, since it doesn't do precisely what you asked for. But it's the best thing that I can think of that doesn't depend on too much magic.

You should check that the `DISPLAY` environment variable is set before going with GUI code too, since it won't work without that.

Note that terminal users can still redirect `stdin` or `stdout` to `/dev/null` (for example) and this might cause your program to go with the GUI behaviour. So it's far from perfect.

Finally, even though I've given you an answer, please don't do this! It is confusing to users for a program's behaviour to change depending on how it was called.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python

from Tkinter import *
from tkMessageBox import *
import os
import sys

if os.isatty(sys.stdout.fileno()):
  print "CLI - isatty TRUE"
else:
  showinfo('Title', "GUI - isatty FALSE")

Comment: The above code works as expected, thanks!!!
yes, running the script as "python test-invocation.py > /dev/null" will trick the script and display the GUI dialog box, but it is still good enough since users are internal, not public.

It will be perfect if there is some check that can avoid launching it from cli with "> dev/null" to make the program go with GUI behaviour.

Comment: And what should we do? Two different scripts / modules, one for terminal executions and another one for the executions coming from the OS GUI? It's my opinion that if the script is small it's not worth. Is there any smart way for doing this in one file?

Comment: IMHO, what the program does from the command line should be consistent so as to not be surprising to users. Decide that the CLI is the default, for example, and provide a `--gui` option. Add a separate executable that is just a wrapper that runs the main script with `--gui` if you like. If you decide that you must change behaviour automatically, consider adding options to disable that functionality (for example with `--gui` and `--no-gui` options). For desktop users, use a `.desktop` file that uses `--gui`.

Comment: Deciding that users aren't advanced enough to use aliases or options and providing magically changing behaviour as a substitute is short sighted IMHO. Imagine if every program did this. Non-advanced users would be hindered in making progress in understanding the system because of its lack of consistency. And advanced users would get frustrated when writing scripts because they may work when written but suddenly fail when the environment is different.

Answer (score 4):

It can check the value of `$DISPLAY` to see whether or not it's running under X11, and `$(tty)` to see whether it's running on an interactive terminal. `if [[ $DISPLAY ]] && ! tty; then` chances are good you'd want to display a GUI popup.

Answer (score 3):

In the .desktop file that is the menu-entry in gnome/kde/whatever, add a parameter such as

```
yourcommand --gui
```

so the program will be able to know.

Comment: I recommend this answer over mine if the question is how to specify rather than detect different methods of invocations.

Answer (score 2):

Following on to LtWorf's answer (I couldn't describe all this in a comment)

---

Rather than, or in addition to, a parameter, you can create a shell script then create a second link to it with a different name, say `somprog` and `gsomeprog` where "gsomeprog" is equivalent to "someprog -gui"

```
$ mv mydevdir/someprog /usr/local/bin
$ cd /usr/local/bin
$ ln someprog gsomeprog
```

I prefer hard links to `ln -s` in this case because the "two" programs will always sit next to each other, and will never leave a dangling soft link.

In the shell script, check the name that was used to invoke it by inspecting arg zero

```
#!/bin/sh

mode=console

if [ $(basename ${0}) = gst -o "${1}" = "-gui" ]; then
    mode=gui
fi

echo "Mode is ${mode}"
```

There is, of course, better option processing than `"${1}" = "-gui"` available, but that is left as an exercise for the reader.

---

I like Robie Basak's answer, but be aware of his `someprog > /dev/null` caveat.

Comment: Thanks for you opinion, another link/program to program makes thing getting more complex... 
Yea, still figuring how to get rid of "someprog > /dev/null" to make the check more perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You could also run some X11 utility like `xdpyinfo`; if it runs correctly, you have an X11 server so you are in GUI mode, e.g. in bash

```
if xdpyinfo | grep X.Org > /dev/null ; then
```